# Does one grey tick in WhatsApp group chats mean that I am blocked?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm still trying to figure out WhatsApp. I want to know if I am blocked. So I am in a group with 50 people (nearly all people are not in my saved contacts, only 2 are). I sent a message, and after more than 12 hours, my message is still shown with one grey tick.

The profile picture of my friends that are saved on my mobile is still showing.

Am I blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One grey tick in WhatsApp group chats means that *someone* has not received the messages** (e.g. no internet, the device is powered off, etc.)

Users can check the real status by long-tapping their own messages and selecting "Info" (tap the "3-vertical dot" overflow menu if it's not shown). It will show:

- Participants who have read the messages
- Participants who have received the messages, and
- A count of participants who have not received the messages as "x remaining"

---

On the other hand, **blocking participants in WhatsApp group chats does not affect anything**.

I just tested this with a group consisting of my 2 WhatsApp accounts, with the recipient blocking the sender:

- When sending private messages

  - Sender: one grey tick (undelivered)
  - Recipient: not receiving the messages
- When sending group chat messages

  - Sender: double grey (delivered) / blue (read) ticks
  - Recipient: still receiving the messages and sending read receipts